# Id's of immutable types

Tags: python

I'm a little confused about the distinction between mutable and immutable objects. I tried the following chunk of code to find the id's of objects:

```
tuple1 = ('Object1', 'Object2')
print id(tuple1)
tuple2 = ('Object1', 'Object2')
print id(tuple2)
list1 = ['Object1', 'Object2']
print id(list1)
list2 = ['Object1', 'Object2']
print id(list2)
string1 = "Foo bar"
print id(string1)
string2 = "Foo bar"
print id(string2)
```

I got the same id for the strings, and different id's for the lists, but a different id for the tuples. Shouldn't they have the same id? I was wondering if someone could explain how that works?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Same IDs means the *exact* same object, but an implementation of Python is free to optimize the creation of immutable objects as it pleases.  For example, in CPython 2.6.6 small integer objects are cached, so:

```
>>> x=256
>>> x is 256
True
>>> x=1024
>>> x is 1024
False

[NOTE: 'is' tests for object identity (same ID)]
```

There are no guarantees this result will be the same in other implementations.  An implementation *could* cache immutable tuples, but which tuples are common? If as you suggest all identical tuples return the same id, then all tuples created by a program would have to be cached, and each new creation of a tuple would have to search the cache to see if it had been created before, which would be time consuming.

Use `==` to test for object equality, regardless of ID.

Comment: Tuple literals are created during compile time. They are stored in `co_consts` of the code object and loaded in a single step using a `LOAD_CONST` operation. The time involved in creating them is during compile time. They really should probably just be interned by default.

Answer (score 3):

You get the same id with the strings because string literals can be [interned](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interning). You don't get the same id for the tuples because tuples are not interned.

A data structure that is mutable can not reasonably be interned (read: doing so would cause very confusing behaviour), so if strings were mutable, they could not be interned. However this does not mean that all immutable data structures are interned.

Comment: "You get the same id with the strings because string literals are interned." Is this in 3.x?

Comment: It's not quite true that strings are always interned unless something has changed since I last looked into it. Python reserves the right to not do so although in practice, it generally does with short strings that look like dictionary keys.

Comment: @aaron: Strings certainly aren't always interned, but I was under the impression that string literals are. At least a quick test showed that string literals with 1001 characters are interned in python 2.6.6.

Comment: @sepp2k. Try `a = 'foo bar'; b = 'foo bar'; a is b`. On my system at least, it's `False` because they are not valid identifiers and don't get interned.

Comment: @aaron: On my system they are, but you've convinced me that this is not guaranteed. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: @sepp2k. Out of curiosity, what version of Python is it? I get `False` on both 2.65 and 3.1 on a linux system.

Comment: @aaron: I get True on both python 3.1.2 and 2.6.6 on Ubuntu 10.10. So it's either a recent change or a compile-flag on ubuntu's build of python.

Comment: @sepp2k.  I see the issue. When you put it all on one like as I posted, the interpreter interns it. If you do it on separate lines in the interpreter (which is what I actually did) then you get the behavior I described. Here's a [gist](https://gist.github.com/718346) that demonstrates the behavior in an actual file which is far more important.

Answer (score 1):

Immatable means that you can not change the instance of class. For example:

```
salad = ["Lettuce","Tomato","Onion","Tuna"]
fruit = ("Apple","Banana","Cherry","Fig","Grapefruit")
salad[3] = "Cheese"   # works
fruit[3] = "Orange"   # error message
```

Answer (score 1):

By default, interpreter creates just one shared objects for small integers or strings.